# ElasticSearch field with different types in one single index

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a scenario in a service that accepts multiple types of data and we want to store in ElasticSearch so we can benefit from its search capabilities.

Data could be a String, Number, Object or an Array of objects as the following:

```
POST my-index/_doc/1
{
  "additionalData": [
    {
      "values": {
        "some-field": "some-value",
        "some-other-field": "some-value"
      }
    }
  ]
}

POST my-index/_doc/1
{
  "additionalData": [
    {
      "values": [12345, 9875]
    }
  ]
}

POST my-index/_doc/1
{
  "additionalData": [
    {
      "values": "Some text"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to store that in elasticSearch? or better to store in other NoSQL Databases like Mongodb?

PS: we are using Es 7.x, and would like to keep using ES.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to search on those values, it's possible with a disabled field (i.e. not indexed, not stored)

However, if you want to search on those value, it's not possible. Each field must have a specific type (object, numeric, text, etc) and then you can only store values of that type in the field.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate! we actually want to use those values for search as well, are you aware of any database that might be forgiven about schema and have search capabilities like ES? thanks in advance